# How do I make my Android app available only to handsets?

Tags: android, google-play

My app is designed specifically for handsets, but when I try to upload the app to market it shows that my app is visible to tablets (xlarge) too. I intentionally don't want my app to be displayed in market if accessed from tablets.

I tried playing around with minSdkVersion and targetVersion support and also   elements.

I also tried using

```
<manifest ... >
    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
    ...
    <application ... >
        ...
    <application>
</manifest>
```

But I get an error:

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>     - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'screenDensity' in package
>      'android'
>     - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'screenSize' in package
>      'android'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [market filters](http://d.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html) to specify exactly those things your application really needs. If the device needs to be a cellphone, add `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"/>`

Filtering out tablets by specifying compatible screen sizes makes no sense. See [<uses-feature>](http://d.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) for the list of hardware features. Don't simply add elements just for the sake of filtering, the manifest should specify what the application requires in order to work.

Comment: Considering tablets don't have telephony service, using this filter will help.But my app don't require any hardware configuration for it to function. My app is very specifically done for Handsets(devices from small to large) and over that I don't want negative reviews because app is not functioning as expected in tablets.

Comment: The XML you posted works fine here, what is your project build target?

Comment: Have you tried a rebuild? Disable Project > Build Automatically, do Project > Clean and then enable automatic building again. If you changed your build target, also right-click the project in package explorer and select Android Tools > Fix Project Properties. Do this right after cleaning before your next build.

Comment: Hey, I got it working.... thanks for the help. By the way... I also made a mistake of running the project in SDK version 8 library but marked the targetSDK as 10. This was the reason <compatible-screens> was not recognizable by the compiler. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `<supports-screens>` tag?

```
<manifest ... >
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="false"
                      android:largestWidthLimitDp="600" />
    <application>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

For more information, you can refer to this.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if this is the right way to go about it. But, I came across some this once and used it in my app to ensure that tablet users don't get to access this application on their devices.

```
//verify the android version running on the phone/device
int currentDeviceVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

//since tablets would be running HoneyComb or higher
if (currentDeviceVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
    // display message that app is not supported for android honeycomb and above
    // End (finish) app
}
```

Comment: This may work after the device has downloaded and installed the app. I need some filter to make the app invisible for tablets.

Comment: No, don't do this. New devices like the Galaxy Nexus which is very much a phone will not be able to use your app.

Answer (score 0):

By taking a look into the device catalogue of the play console, you need to specify more screenDensity values. (See below, as of today) I think there is always the risk of seeing new values popping up in the device catalogue. So you should constantly monitor the amount of devices your app does not support.

```
    <!-- Exclude Tablets -->
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="213" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="280" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="360" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="400" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="420" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="213" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="280" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="360" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="400" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="420" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />
</compatible-screens>
```